# How to add new column's name in dataframe saving previous one (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have this with column name = `A`:

```
   A
0  B
1  C
2  D
```

How to make this with column name = `N`:

```
   N
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
```

this not working in my case:

```
df.columns = ['N']
```

is it pandasmic way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.T.reset_index().set_axis(['N']).T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   N
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
```

It is a lot easier to move a dataframe index into the columns of a dataframe than to move the column header of a dataframe into a row of a dataframe.

---

```
pd.concat([df.columns.to_series(name='A').to_frame(),df])\
  .reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'A':'N'})
```

Output:

```
   N
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
```

Comment: oh my gash, i'd never make it up by myself, thanks) first one is more then correct) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new dataframe by adding the column names at the start of the `df`.

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'N': [*df.columns, *df.squeeze()]})

   N
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
```

---

We can also use `pd.concat` here.

```
out = pd.concat(
    [df.columns.to_series(), df.squeeze()], ignore_index=True
).to_frame("N")

   N
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
```

Comment: In my case i don't know exactly what is the name of column (A), so the Scott Boston's answer with .T. already solve two problem with one line code). Thanks for help

Comment: @КонстантинПрудников Is it always that df always has only one column?

Comment: ye, i just get txt file from form input request into df:
df = pd.read_fwf(file_txt) - so only one column

Comment: @КонстантинПрудников Check the edited answer.